# Footer to be at the end of the page, not fixed

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I use Bootstrap 4 and angular 7. 
I have main component where I have header, place for my component and footer. My header and footer is separate component. This is example:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

I want to my footer to be on end of the page, not fixed. But hi is Always fixed. This is my footer:

```
<footer class="footer fixed-bottom">
    ...
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use flexboxes.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  background: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: column
}

header {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  background: lightblue;
}

content {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightgreen;
}

footer {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  background: coral;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header></header>
  <content>
    <!-- <div style="height: 1800px"></div> -->
  </content>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

As you can see, the footer is always at the end of the page, provided that the container is the size of the said page.

If you uncomment the div, you will see the container expands and keeps your footer at the end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class `fixed-bottom` from your footer tag

```
<footer class="footer">
    ...
</footer>
```

NOTE: if your page content is not reaching the view height you'll have to add a `min-height` style to your page in order to get the footer at the bottom of the view

HTML:

```
<div class="my-container">
  <!-- your page content -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-container {
  min-height: 800px;
  /* 800px as your view height, change it accordingly */
}
```

Comment: But now is not on the end of the page.

Comment: It is at the end of the page, it's just that your page is not taking the whole view height. you can add a css style to your page `min-height: 800px` with the 800px has your view height

Answer (score 0):

> end of the page, not fixed.

if it means to say: Footer at the bottom of the content. Which is not viewable untill we scroll it down to the last of the page.

You just need to make the footer tag with no class will solve your problem.

```
<footer>
   //Your Footer Content
</footer>
```

> end of the page, not fixed.

if it means to say: [Sticky Footer](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/) than add the following code in  `footer.component.css`

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Comment: But now is not on the end of the page.

Comment: Yes, exactly that I have. But this is not solve my problem.

Comment: You need to clarify it more clearly @SiCiPin what exactly you were looking for.